# Javascript - data filtering and removing line breaks

Tags: javascript

A list of isbn's are entered in the text area and javascript opens an amazon search for each one entered.

Isbn's can be between 10 or 13 digits.
Not all isbn searches start with an isbn, sometimes there can be information in front such as "isbn10:0195433831" so you cant count from the start.

For Example, this is a typical search:

0195433831 Good

0195433831 Poor

0195433831 Excellent

**Question**

Often times isbn's are entered in a different format breaking it, for example:

1) With spacing between numbers

978 0 132 76682 1 like new

978 0 495 38500 4 very good

2) With additional rating numbers added creating additional unnecessary 
searches.

9781118624616 9/10 condition with minimal highlighting

9780415462020 10/10 condition, brand new

So I must find a way to have Javascript filter out these conditions.

Code is here:

```js
//the input box.
var input = document.getElementById('numbers');

//adding an event listener for change on the input box
input.addEventListener('input', handler, false);

//function that runs when the change event is emitted
function handler () {
    var items = input.value.replace(/\r?\n/g, ' ').split(' ');
      length = items.length;
  console.log('your collection', items);
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if ( items[i] && !isNaN(items[i]) ) {
      console.log('opening page for isbn ', items[i])
      openPage(items[i]);
    }
  }
}

//opens the tab for one isbn number
function openPage (isbn) {
  var base = 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_adv_b/?search-alias=stripbooks&field-isbn='
  window.open(base + isbn)
}
```

```html
<p>... note, after paste you may need to click outside the text area or tab out to fire the change event.</p>

<textarea id=numbers placeholder="paste isbn numbers as csv here">
</textarea>
```

Comment: do the isbns that are entered always start with the barcode and then the rating? if so couldn't you count the numbers that match the length of the barcode and then strip the white space?

Comment: So what do you want, just the isbns?

Comment: Are these 13 digit ISBNs or 10 digit ISBNs or both?

Comment: sbn's can be between 10 or 13 digits. Not all isbn searches start with an isbn, sometimes there can be information in front such as "isbn10:0195433831" so you cant count from the start. I want the Javascript to do is normal search in the code even if isbn searches are formatted wrong such as additional numbers are involved such as a rating in front of it "9/10" or there are spaces between an isbn "978 0 2424 24".

Answer (score 0):

ISBNs should be 13 numbers if I remember right so can't you just remove the whitespace and match groups of 13?

```
var str = "978 111 862 4616 9/10 condition with minimal highlighting\n\n9780415462020 10/10 condition, brand new",
    nums = str.replace(/\s/,"").match(/\d{13}/g);
```

Comment: Good, but ISBNs can also be 10 characters if printed [before 2007.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number)

Comment: You need the `g` modifier to remove all the spaces: `/\s/g`.

Comment: To handle both formats, you could use `.match(/\d{13}|\d{10}/g)`

Comment: not really... with the format of random ratings after it, that would give wrong numbers...

Comment: I added an extra command " var items = input.value.replace(/\s/g, ''); " but for some reason this does not work.